# Using Fluxbox's Deco option in the apps file

Tags: linux, xorg, fluxbox

I'm trying to configure Fluxbox to show my xterms with a specific subset of window decorations.

[This blog post](http://my.opera.com/coreymwamba/blog/2009/05/14/fluxbox-the-deco-bitmask-mystery-solved) is where I'm getting my information from.

Here's what I have in my ~/.fluxbox/apps:

```
[app] (name=xterm) (class=XTerm)
    [Dimensions] {660 400}
    [Deco] {519}
[end]
```

This should give xterms a titlebar, handle/grips, border, and enable tabbing.

It kind of works, but I'm still getting the minimize, maximize, close and sticky buttons.

Any idea how I can get rid of them?

**Also** - can someone please add a fluxbox tag, I don't have any rep on superuser!

Comment: looks like a bug, i ll have a look at the code tomorrow, hopefully
(-> akira @ fluxbox.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the bug should be fixed [now](http://git.fluxbox.org/?p=fluxbox.git;a=commitdiff;h=5a3f25cda17d5381873431a5404944b63176c966) in git, with the next release you should get it as well

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a quick look at the FluxBox Wiki site to see if I can find any information that might be of help to you and I found these:

Make windows only show a border (with tabs if you want)
[FluxBox Wiki - Make windows only show a border](http://fluxbox-wiki.org/index.php?title=Make_windows_only_show_a_border)

There's another wiki page there that tells you how to edit the apps file... unfortunately I'm only allowed to post one link as I'm new.

Hope this link helps,
Tim